# Python to separate both comma and hyphen to lint in order wise

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip, ip-address

Below is the file output.

```
IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.10
```

I need to send IP address to list in order wise. I used below script and its works fine.

```
list1 = []
def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   print end
   temp = start
   ip_range = []
   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while temp != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))
   print ip_range   
   return ip_range
my_dict = {}
with open("test5.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      keyin = line.split(":")
      key = keyin[0]
      linecomma = line.split(":")
      items = linecomma[1].split("-")
      values = items[0:]
      my_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
   if k == "IP":
      start_ip,end_ip = v[0], v[1]
```

Now my input file is like below:

```
IP:10.10.10.11,10.10.10.2-10.10.10.10,10.10.10.13,10.10.10.10.14-10.10.10.16
```

Now I need list ip_range is like below:

```
['10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5', '10.10.10.6', '10.10.10.7', '10.10.10.8', '10.10.10.9', '10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.13', '10.10.10.14', '10.10.10.15', '10.10.10.16']
```

Note: order wise means not ascending order or descending order. Its depends up on test5.txt file

Note: test5.txt file may have random  output one example is above and below are the two other  examples.

```
  Example1:
  IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.10,10.10.10.20,10.10.10.10.14-10.10.10.16
  Example2:
  IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.16
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @Scott Hunter, above code is my effort and I have not getting any idea further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to convert the IP address back into a number and then count until the whole range of numbers is used. This would then also work for examples such as `10.0.1.250-10.0.2.5`

```
import socket
import struct

ip_addresses = []

with open("test5.txt") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        if line.startswith('IP:'):
            for entry in line.split(':')[1].split(','):
                ip_range = entry.split('-', 1)

                if len(ip_range) == 2:
                    start_ip = struct.unpack('>L', socket.inet_aton(ip_range[0].replace('-', '.')))[0]
                    end_ip = struct.unpack('>L', socket.inet_aton(ip_range[1].replace('-', '.')))[0]

                    while start_ip <= end_ip:
                        ip_addresses.append(socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>L', start_ip)))
                        start_ip += 1
                else:
                    ip_addresses.append(ip_range[0])

print ip_addresses
```

So if `test5.txt` contained:

```
IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.10,10.10.10.20,10.10.10.14-10.10.10.16
IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.16
IP:10.0.1.250-10.0.2.5
IP:172.168.1.100,172.168.1.1-172.168.1-10,172.168.1.11-172.168.1-20
```

You would get the following output:

```
['10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5', '10.10.10.6', '10.10.10.7', '10.10.10.8', '10.10.10.9', '10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.20', '10.10.10.14', '10.10.10.15', '10.10.10.16', '10.10.10.1', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5', '10.10.10.6', '10.10.10.7', '10.10.10.8', '10.10.10.9', '10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.12', '10.10.10.13', '10.10.10.14', '10.10.10.15', '10.10.10.16', '10.0.1.250', '10.0.1.251', '10.0.1.252', '10.0.1.253', '10.0.1.254', '10.0.1.255', '10.0.2.0', '10.0.2.1', '10.0.2.2', '10.0.2.3', '10.0.2.4', '10.0.2.5', '172.168.1.100', '172.168.1.1', '172.168.1.2', '172.168.1.3', '172.168.1.4', '172.168.1.5', '172.168.1.6', '172.168.1.7', '172.168.1.8', '172.168.1.9', '172.168.1.10', '172.168.1.11', '172.168.1.12', '172.168.1.13', '172.168.1.14', '172.168.1.15', '172.168.1.16', '172.168.1.17', '172.168.1.18', '172.168.1.19', '172.168.1.20']
```

[`socket.inet_ntoa()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=ntoa#socket.inet_ntoa) takes an IP address in string format and converts into a binary format. [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.unpack#struct.unpack) takes a packed binary formatted number and converts it into a number, e.g. `0.0.0.1` would convert to `1`. The script then just needs to count normally until the end number is reached, each time reversing the conversions to recreate an IP address in string format.

Comment: Great!, It works. To understand your script I need 1 week i guess :). Thanks a lot Martin

Comment: Firstly... `172.158.1-20` should be `172.158.1.20` according to your spec. The script can now handle that though. Secondly, the text you have posted is in `utf-8` format which will break it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `split`

```
ip = 'IP:10.10.10.11,10.10.10.2-10.10.10.10,10.10.10.13,10.10.10.10.14-
ip_address = ip.split('IP:')[-1]
result = []
for item in ip_address.split(','):
    if '-' in item:
        start,end = map(lambda x:int(x.split('.')[-1]),item.split('-'))
        start_ip = '.'.join(item.split('-')[0].split('.')[:-1])
        result += [start_ip+'.'+str(i) for i in range(start,end+1)]
    else:
        result.append(item)
```

Result

```
['10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4', '10.10.10.5', '10.10.10.6', '10.10.10.7', '10.10.10.8', '10.10.10.9', '10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.13', '10.10.10.10.14', '10.10.10.10.15', '10.10.10.10.16']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define two functions: one to convert and IP address to a 32-bit integer (which is what it actually is), and another to convert an integer to an IP address string.

```
def ip_to_int(ip):
    return sum(int(octet) * 256**(i) for i,octet in enumerate(reversed(ip.split('.'))))

def int_to_ip(x):
    ip = []
    for i in range(3,-1,-1):
        octet, x = divmod(x, 256**i)
        ip.append(str(octet))
    return '.'.join(ip)
```

We can use these functions to convert IP range strings to integer ranges which are are easy to iterate over.  This also has the benefit of handling ranges such as `10.10.10.250-10.10.11.3`, should they appear.

```
if line.startswith('IP:'):
    ip_list = line.strip().replace('IP:','').split(',')
    for ip_range in ip_list:
        ip_ints = [ip_to_int(ip) for ip in ip_range.split('-')]
        ip_addresses.extend([int_to_ip(ip_int) for ip_int in range(ip_ints[0], ip_ints[-1]+1)])
```

Some tests:

```
line = 'IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.10,10.10.10.20,10.10.10.14-10.10.10.16\n'
# returns:
['10.10.10.1',
 '10.10.10.2',
 '10.10.10.3',
 '10.10.10.4',
 '10.10.10.5',
 '10.10.10.6',
 '10.10.10.7',
 '10.10.10.8',
 '10.10.10.9',
 '10.10.10.10',
 '10.10.10.20',
 '10.10.10.14',
 '10.10.10.15',
 '10.10.10.16']


line = 'IP:10.0.1.250-10.0.2.5\n'
# returns:
['10.0.1.250',
 '10.0.1.251',
 '10.0.1.252',
 '10.0.1.253',
 '10.0.1.254',
 '10.0.1.255',
 '10.0.2.0',
 '10.0.2.1',
 '10.0.2.2',
 '10.0.2.3',
 '10.0.2.4',
 '10.0.2.5']
```